# How to treat null as 0 when use addition in sql with out IFNULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which add many thing in a expression. Like this `select a+b+c+d+e ...`.
But some of them may be null and I want to treat null value as 0.

I know I can use `IFNULL` like `select ifnull(a,0)+ifnull(b,0)+ifnull(c,0)+ifnull(d,0)+ifnull(e,0)`, but I have many queries and this seems laboursome.

Is there some easy way like a function to achieve the same result?

Comment: Another option is the [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp) function.

Comment: But that's basically the same as `ifnull`

Comment: Please tag the actual RDBMS you are using. I'm guessing mysql, as sql server doesn't have an IFNULL function afaik.

Comment: No, there is no easier way.

Comment: No, there isn't a shortcut. IFNULL **if** you want to handle **NULL**s...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you will need to use indeed either `IFNULL` or `IF`.

However, if you have lots of them, and you are in control of the schema, I would suggest defining your fields as `.. NOT NULL DEFAULT 0` (explicit default is good). This way, you will not need `IFNULL` any longer.